# "Get someone going"

Tags: phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning

> A: We have to reduced energy usage by %15. That means no more
>   laminating Santiago.
>
> B: Oh, that's fine. It is not the thing that gives me the most
>   pleasure in life. Interacting other people, that's what ***gets me
>   going***. (B is real nerd. She likes everyhing about planning,
>   binders, pencils, etc. B says this line in not a persuasive way. She
>   really takes pleasure laminating her papers.

This dialogue is from an american sitcom.

What does "get me going" mean. I have made a research on internet but I think here ıt means different than the meanings I have find out while searching. I suppose it means something like "gives me motivation to live". But I am not sure.

Answer (score 2):

"Gets me going" can work in the sense of getting you excited about doing something, but it's imprecise. It can also mean "makes me mad" or "wakes me up" or a number of other interpretations. I would recommend "Interacting with other people, that's what I enjoy" or "That's what motivates me."